# Exporting shapefile to Google Earth format (*.kmz) using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, google-earth, kmz

Is there a way to export a shapefile to Google Earth format (*.kmz) using QGIS?

Comment: this might help you: http://www.stevencanplan.com/2009/converting-shapefiles-and-kml-files/

Comment: Right click on the layer and choose "Save As..." and Format = Keyhole Markup Language [KML].  A KMZ is simply a compressed version of a KML file.

Answer (score 6):

QGIS will not save/export straight to KMZ. As Aaron suggests in his comment above, you can right click on your layer in QGIS, select 'Save As...' and choose KML.

To then convert your KML to a KMZ, you have two options:

1. Open the KML in Google Earth, right click on 'Save Place As...', and select KMZ as your desired format.
2. Put your KML in a .zip file, then change the file extension to .kmz. You will now have a working KMZ file you can open in Google Earth as normal.

Comment: In my QGIS 3.10.4, "KML" or "Keyhole Markup Language" is not shown as an option for possible export option when Export -> Save As.

Answer (score 4):

Check this plugin out. It exports also the symbols as displayed in a QGIS layer:

http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/layer2kmz/