# Using QGIS to reduce the size of a KML file

Tags: qgis, kml

I've saved an Esri shapefile in QGIS as a KML file to load into Google Fusion tables.  However I notice the file size has increased significantly when saved as a KML.  Previous posts have suggested using OS2OGR to do this.

Comment: Look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58801/exporting-shapefile-to-google-earth-format-kmz-using-qgis  You want to convert your kml to a kmz (which is just a zipped up version of the kml) either via Google Earth itself or via a zip and extension name change.

Comment: For some types of datasets, KML is inherently less efficient.  Zipping KML into KMZ can reduce the file size, but depending on what you're doing that may or may not be helpful.  KML file sizes can often be reduced by limiting the number of decimal places used in the coordinate strings.  Sometimes it can help to change the way attribute data is saved, or whether it's saved to the KML at all.  But neither of those are easy to adjust in QGIS.  Also, note that Fusion Tables (RIP) was shut down in Dec 2019: https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2018/12/google-fusion-tables-to-be-shut-down-on.html