# Saving shapefile as one file retaining symbology

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, qgis-3, symbology, kmz

I have used Python inside QGIS 3.24 to create many contour maps from data.
The contour maps are in the format `shp`, and I saved the graduated symbology as a `qml` file with the same name as the shapefile [as in this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/77073/95891).

Now, I want to share the files with my colleagues as `kmz` format, I saved the `shp` file as `kml`, then put the latter to a zip file, and renamed the result to `kmz` as I learned from [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/213827/95891). Unfortunately, the symbology was not saved to the KML file, so I tried to put the `qml` file with the `kml` in the same zip (`kmz`) file, but it didn't show the symbology as well!
Now I have five files for each map as shapefile, with symbology (`shp`, `prj`, `shx`, `dbf`, and `qml`), and it is hard to share all these files for each layer.

Is there any method or format to save the `shp` file with symbology in one file like the `kmz` or so?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - could you describe what you are trying to do as well as what you have tried so far. Why do you need to save the symbology with the data?

Comment: @IanTurton, I want to share the shapefiles to friends with symbology to save their time redoing it. I've created more than 300 maps for climatic properties distribution. Sharing such maps without symbology is tedious.

Comment: If you are sharing maps then PDF is a good format, if you are sharing data then the shapefiles (or better geopackages) are a good format. These are entirely different goals though

Comment: @IanTurton I want to share the layers so that they can add them to their project, then perform further processing like adding layers to specify the priority zones. I thought about KMZ files because they sent me several files of this extension, I used the, then converted my CSV data to TIF by interpolation, then to SHP files by contouring. I did all of this through python, and want to send them my work to benefit from it.

Comment: maybe you need a geopackage with the qgis project inside it